# How to use YouTube API with Gulp (minified file doesn't contain YouTube callback methods)

Tags: javascript, gulp, youtube-javascript-api, laravel-elixir

I can't use **[YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)** methods because they are deleted by **[Laravel Elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir#javascript)** (Gulp) in my minified `.js` file.

Methods such as below are not included in my my minified `.js` file because they aren't called in `.js` files I created (In fact, they are called in [YouTube iFrame API](https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api)).

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady
onPlayerReady
onPlayerStateChange
```

Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution for this is to call `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`.

To do that, I added a condition :

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(init) {
   if (init === "init") {
       return;
   }
   // Init your YouTube Player here, after the condition.
}

// First call here : The minifier notices the method is used, so it won't delete it
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady("init");

// Later, YouTube API will call this method
// (YouTube doesn't pass any parameters, so the player will be initialized in this case)
// YouTube API : onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
```